# iOS Swift 5, Auto Release CoreText & CoreGraphics memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, core-graphics, core-text

I am using CoreText and CoreGraphics to load fonts from files within a directory, and then categories them according to the supported unicode characters in the font metadata using the following code, in a for loop :

```
if let provider = CGDataProvider(url: fontFileURL as CFURL) {
    if let font = CGFont(provider) {
        let ctFont = CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont(font, 12, nil, nil)

        let chSet = CTFontCopyCharacterSet(ctFont)

        let cSet = chSet as CharacterSet

        let isAr = cSet.contains(Unicode.Scalar.init(unicodeScalarLiteral: "ب"))
        let isEn = cSet.contains(Unicode.Scalar.init(unicodeScalarLiteral: "b"))
        print(++index, isAr, isEn)
    }
}
```

but at some point in time before the fore loop finished looping the files, the app crashed with the error message `Terminated due to memory issue`, so I suspect that either one of these four function leaks memory, or at lease I don't handle there memory  properly:

```
CGDataProvider: constructor
CGFont: constructor
CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont: func to convert CGFont to CTFont
CTFontCopyCharacterSet: get a copy of CharacterSet supported by the CTFont
```

I tried wrap the code with `autoreleasepool` but did not help.

Please Is there any way to release any allocated memory before continuing  the loop to the next font file !!!

Comment: With `CGFontCreateWithDataProvider()`, I would expect a `CFRelease()`. Could you show your code with the Autorelease pool, and did you try to use Instruments to see a leaking line?

Comment: Note that with the `copy`, I might expect a release too. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1521153-cfrelease documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting this code from the for loop into another function does the trick of releasing the associated memory with the loaded CGFont and the copied CharacterSet.